# read XYPlot size after each change in ChartPanel

Tags: java, jfreechart

You know that getPreferredSize method exists for ChartPanel.I want a similar method for XYPlot.Because I have a background image, I will scale image for each plot size change in ChartPanel.XYPLot width is not important for me.I want to scale height of background.
So I need to have size of XYPlot.

Changes can be Windows resize changes, also you know that XYPlot size is affected from domainAxis items, Legend items.

P.S: I know that I can read plot info in ChartEvent.I want to have coordinates without trigger mouse event.

EDIT:I am creating panel with following code.Another class calls this method, then adds JPanel with ChartPanel to JFrame

```
public void createPanel() {

    XYPlot historyPlot = createHistoryPlot();
    /** read forecast result job specific */

    /** Creates future XYPlot */
    XYPlot futurePlot = createFuturePlot();
    /** range axis for CombinedRangeXYPlot */
    final ValueAxis rangeAxis = new NumberAxis("");
    CombinedRangeXYPlot plot = new CombinedRangeXYPlot(rangeAxis);
    /** add subplot to plot */
    plot.setGap(0);
    plot.add(historyPlot, 1);
    plot.add(futurePlot, 1);
    /** Creates new plot includes combinedRange plot */
    chart = new JFreeChart("", JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, true);
    panel = new ChartPanel(chart, true, true, true, false, true);
    /** not enable zoom */
    panel.setDomainZoomable(false);
    panel.setRangeZoomable(false);
    panel.validate();
    panel.setVisible(true);
    this.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}
```

Then I am trying to customize graph with following code.It is invoked outer class after createPanel method is called.So ChartPAnel is created with subplots in it.

```
/**
 * Customizes graph view.Changes view related settings.
 * @param chart
 *            JFreeChart instance
 */
private void customizeGraphView(JFreeChart chart) {
    CombinedRangeXYPlot combinedPlot = (CombinedRangeXYPlot) chart.getPlot();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    /** read 2 subplot*/
    List<XYPlot> subPlots = combinedPlot.getSubplots();
    for (int plotIndex = 0; plotIndex < subPlots.size(); plotIndex++) {
        /** get plot */
        XYPlot plot = subPlots.get(plotIndex);
        /** do not show domain grid lines */
        plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(false);
        XYItemRenderer itemRenderer = plot.getRenderer();
        /** if line and shape renderer */
        if (itemRenderer instanceof StandardXYItemRenderer) {
            StandardXYItemRenderer renderer = (StandardXYItemRenderer) itemRenderer;
            /** show shapes in time series */
            renderer.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
            /** fill shapes in time series */
            renderer.setBaseShapesFilled(true);
            renderer.setBaseFillPaint(Color.BLACK);
            // addItemLabels(renderer);
        }
        /** add severity bar for BackGround image for 2 subplot */
        if (plotIndex == 0) {
            addBackGroundImage(plot, Align.RIGHT);
        } else {
/** returns java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double[x=0.0,y=0.0,w=0.0,h=0.0] */

            panel.getScreenDataArea()
            addBackGroundImage(plot, Align.LEFT);
        }
        plot.setOutlineVisible(false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=110126).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [`drawBackgroundImage()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/Plot.html#drawBackgroundImage%28java.awt.Graphics2D,%20java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D%29) does this for you when you use [`setBackgroundImage()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/Plot.html#setBackgroundImage%28java.awt.Image%29). If not, you can override [`drawBackground()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/Plot.html#drawBackground%28java.awt.Graphics2D,%20java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D%29) to alter the existing behavior.

Addendum: The `Rectangle2D` parameter sent to `drawBackground()` should supply the geometry you want.

Addendum: This example that overrides [`drawBackground()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/Plot.html#drawBackground%28java.awt.Graphics2D,%20java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D%29) shows the plot's `Rectangle2D`. Note that `ChartPanel` inherits the default layout of `JPanel`, which is `FlowLayout`.

Console:

```
java.awt.Rectangle[x=8,y=28,width=664,height=388]
```

Code:

```
public Test() {
    Image image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
    XYPlot plot = new XYPlot() {

        @Override
        public void drawBackground(Graphics2D g2, Rectangle2D area) {
            super.drawBackground(g2, area);
            System.out.println(area);
        }
    };
    plot.setBackgroundImage(image);
    JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Test", plot);
    ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    this.add(panel);
}
```

Comment: But I can not use.chartPanel.getChartRenderingInfo().getPlotInfo().getSubplotInfo(0).getDataArea().It returns null values.My problem is this.I have to force ChartPanel to repaint, so I can get coordinates. I can not understand why noone can answer this question.Everybody says that use ChartMouseEvent.But I do not have to click chart to read data area coordinates

Comment: The background image scales automatically. I didn't mention `ChartMouseEvent` or `ChartPanel`.

Comment: it does not scale automatically.I am using ALIGN.RIGHT.I do not use fit.Because some image points are related to my number axis values.

Comment: An annotation might align with the plot better.

Comment: If you help me to get coordinates with following method, I will scale image.Please help me to read coordinates.They return null values, because Chart is not drawn when I read them:how can I force to draw.chartPanel.getScreenDataArea()

Comment: You could try `validate()` or `pack()` before `setVisible()`. Without your [sscce](http://sscce.org/), I'm just guessing.